# gdb libc function offsets don't match objdump

Tags: assembly, linker, operating-system, shellcode

I am writing some ROP shellcode on 64 bit linux. I have found my gadgets using both 'objdump -d /lib64/libc.so.6' and 'ROPgadget /lib64/libc.so.6'

This simply means that I have chosen offsets from the base of libc that contain assembly instructions that I wish to execute.

Using the values from objdump as an offset from the base address of libc as found in /proc/$pid/maps [1], I crafted my payload. However, some of the gadgets found with both objdump and ROPgadget do not appear when single stepping my code using gdb.

Why does it appear that some libc code is simply missing? Am I using the wrong base address?

[1]

```
7ffff7818000-7ffff79b5000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 5317651                    /lib64/libc-2.19.so
7ffff79b5000-7ffff7bb4000 ---p 0019d000 08:03 5317651                    /lib64/libc-2.19.so
7ffff7bb4000-7ffff7bb8000 r--p 0019c000 08:03 5317651                    /lib64/libc-2.19.so
7ffff7bb8000-7ffff7bba000 rw-p 001a0000 08:03 5317651                    /lib64/libc-2.19.so
```

p.s.

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 12 Dec 11 15:42 /lib64/libc.so.6 -> libc-2.19.so
```

and ASLR is disabled

The missing gadgets:

```
$ objdump -M intel -D /lib64/libc-2.19.so | grep -B1 ret | grep rsp | grep pop
63fd:   5c                      pop    rsp
6a98:   5c                      pop    rsp
```

and just to prove that i can do maths:
0x7ffff7818000+6a98 = 0x7ffff781ea98

```
(gdb) disas 0x7ffff781ea98
No function contains specified address.
```

Comment: Try using `x/i 0x7ffff781ea98` instead, that is not as picky as `disas`.

Comment: imagine that. the instruction is sitting right there. thank you!